# How to include nested for loop in Django framework?

Tags: python, html, django, tastypie

Hi I have two values lists as follows:

```
charts = group_obj.chartgroup.values_list('chart_info_id',flat=True).order_by("orderg", "-id")
order = group_obj.chartgroup.values_list('orderg', flat=True)
```

charts will print values: 1,2,3
order will print values: 9,8,7

passing the values to **html** as:

```
context['assigned_charts'] = charts
context['order'] = order
```

Am using this `values_lists` in my **html** (Django frame work and tastypie) as follows:

```
<div class="row">
        {% for c in assigned_charts %}
        <div class="col-md-{{colmd}}"  style="height: 550px; border:2px solid #CCC">
                <a class="pull-left" href="{% url 'update' c %}">{{ c }}</a>
            <div id="container{{c}}" style="height: 450px"></div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Now am using only one of the `values_list`(charts). How can I use my second `values_list`(order) together with the first one? So that each chart will have their own corresponding order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple fields can be passed to [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list), you must remove `flat=True`.

This will return a tuple that can be iterated over in the template like so:

view:

```
charts = group_obj.chartgroup.values_list('chart_info_id', 'orderg').order_by('orderg', '-id')
context['assigned_charts'] = charts
```

template:

```
{% for chart, order in assigned_charts %}
```